# Extraer objetos de array y unificarlos

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy trabajando un proyecto personal y necesito que este array de objetos pase de verse asi:

```
timeline = [
  [
    {
      title: 'Hola',
      description: 'Que tal',
      image: '',    
      User: [Object]
    },
    {
      title: 'Hola',
      description: 'Que tal',
      image: '',
      User: [Object]
    },
    {
      title: 'Hola',
      description: 'Que tal',
      image: '',
      User: [Object]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      title: 'Hola',
      description: 'Que tal',
      image: '',
      User: [Object]
    }
  ]
]
```

A verse asi:

```
timeline = [
    {
      title: 'Hola',
      description: 'Que tal',
      image: '',
      User: [Object]
    },
    {
      title: 'Hola',
      description: 'Que tal',
      image: '',
      User: [Object]
    },
    {
      title: 'Hola',
      description: 'Que tal',
      image: '',
      User: [Object]
    },
    {
      title: 'Hola',
      description: 'Que tal',
      image: '',
      User: [Object]
    }
  ]
```

Intente resolverlo usando un map de la siguiente forma:

```
const newTimeline = props.timeline.map(timeline => timeline)
```

pero no me da el resultado que busco y no se como seguir afrontandolo si alguien me puede de dar una mano estaría genial

Comment: Puedes usar la función `flat` https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: También puedes acceder directamente al arreglo interno: `const newTimeline = timeline[0];`

Answer (score 1):

podes hacer esto:

```
    var auxarray = []
    timeline.forEach(element => {
    element.forEach(subelement => {
    auxarray.push(subelement);
        })
    });

    timeline = auxarray;
    console.log(timeline)
```

O usar el metodo flat() como te dijeron en los comentarios, podes explorar otras posibilidades no te quedes solo con esto. Simplemente cambio la profundidad del array de 2 a 1 usando un array auxiliar para pasarles los objetos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar Flat o Reduce para estos casos

```js
const timeline = [
  [
    {
      title: 'Hola',
      description: 'Que tal',
      image: '',    
      User: [Object]
    },
    {
      title: 'Hola',
      description: 'Que tal',
      image: '',
      User: [Object]
    },
    {
      title: 'Hola',
      description: 'Que tal',
      image: '',
      User: [Object]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      title: 'Hola',
      description: 'Que tal',
      image: '',
      User: [Object]
    }
  ]
]

const timeline_reduce = timeline.reduce((items, item) => [...items, ...item], [])

console.log({timeline_reduce})

console.log({flat: timeline.flat()})
```

Answer (score 1):

el flat funciona bien.
con esto funcionaria:
 `const timeline2=timeline.flat()`

si timeline la declaraste como let, en lugar de const, tambien sirve:
 `timeline=timeline.flat()`